# connect signals on a child widget slot

Tags: c++, qt, slot

I have some problems with inheritance in widgets and connecting slots. I have created an abstract Widget which inherits from `QWidget`. Here is the prototype :

```
class WidgetParams : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
 public:
     explicit WidgetParams(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent){}
     virtual bool paramChanged() = 0;
 protected:
      bool paramsChanged;
 };
```

Then I created derivated class from `WidgetParams`, for example `WidgetParamsWindows`:

```
class WidgetParamsWindows : public WidgetParams
{
  public:
    explicit WidgetParamsWindows(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual bool paramChanged(){return paramsChanged;}
  private:
    QFormLayout *layout;
    QSpinBox *svertical;
    QSpinBox *shorizontal;
  signals:

  public slots:
    void changeSomeParam(int value);
};
```

In `WidgetParamsWindows`, I have some `QSpinBox`, `QPushButton` etc. to adjust the params.

I connect the `QSpinBox` in `WidetParamsWindows` like this :

```
connect(spinbox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this,SLOT(changeSomeParam(int));
```

After that, I created a `WidgetParamsWindows` and put It in a list of `WidgetParams`, in order to show the correct `WidgetParams` when the user clicks on it.

But when I tried to change the value in the `QSpinBox`, nothing change and I have the following message in the console :

```
QObject::connect: No such slot WidgetParams::changeSomeParam(int)
```

I don't know why the parent Widget takes the slot, instead of `WidgetParamsWindows`, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you share some more code (especially the class definitions)? Did you add the `Q_OBJECT` macro also to `WidgetParamsWindows`? Where is the `changeSomeParam(int)` slot declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `Q_OBJECT` macro in `WidgetParamsWindow`, so `moc` doesn't resolve slot macros, try to add `Q_OBJECT` in `WidgetParamsWindow`

Comment: Thanks Its works It was the only without Q_OBJECT macro, but now I have a problem of 'undefined vtable' in compilation. The Q_OBJECT must add some declaration in order to work ? I check I have other WidgetParams where I don't forget this macro and the compilation work for them.

Comment: @user3627590, did you run qmake before compiling the project?

Comment: Undefined vtable is a problem with virtual functions and polimorphism. Are you declaring paramChanged() in all classes that inherits from WidgetParams?

Comment: Yeah It was that. Thank you everyone for your answers and my apologies for such a tiny mistake. I know the signals and slots works with the Q_OBJECT macro but I didn't know we can still declare it even if the macro is not here and then the parent take the slots if the macro is not declared in the child.